# SVG scale SourceGraphic

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I've got a SVG `feGaussianBlur` filter which is rather slow since it is quite a large blur, and I'm trying to improve performance. One method I thought might improve it was scaling the `SourceGraphic` down first, applying `feGaussianBlur` and scaling it back up. However I cannot find a way to scale the `SourceGraphic`. Is this at all possible?

Comment: You used to be able to use filterRes to do filter ops at higher speed/lower resolution for exactly this reason - it may still work in some browsers although it's been deprecated

Comment: Indeed, it's been removed from both [Chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5235900443262976) and [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=979472)